# Как снять выделение старых маркеров перед выделением новых?

Tags: google-maps-api

При клике добавляется окружность заданного размера, и на координаты попавшие в область ставится маркер. По следующему клику окружность перемещается, но маркеры (которые добавились) остаются. Помогите убрать маркеры при повторном клике, если маркеры не попадают в новую окружность.

И еще не хочет работать `InfoWindow`.

Код:

```js
var map, circle, circleOptions, setCenter, marker;
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.7522200, 37.6155600);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
        {
           "featureType": "water",
           "stylers": [
           { "color": "#00C3E9" },
           { "saturation": 0 }
           ]
        }
        ],
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false
    }
     
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("my_map"), myOptions);
    setCenter = true;
      
     var radius = 10;

    circleOptions = {
        fillColor:"#00C3E9",
        fillOpacity:0.5,
        strokeColor:"#F27900",
        strokeOpacity:1,
        strokeWeight:2,
        clickable:false,
        radius: radius*1000
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        if (setCenter) {
           if (marker != undefined) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }
   
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:event.latLng,
                clickable:true,
                draggable: true,
                icon: 'images/beachflag_null.png'              
            });

            marker.setMap(null);
            circleOptions.center = event.latLng;
            setCenter = false;
             
            if (circle != undefined) {
                circle.setMap(null);
            }
             
            circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
            circle.setMap(map);
            setCenter = true;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.749860, 37.673670);
            if (distHaversine(latlng, circleOptions.center) < radius) {
                var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "текст"
                });
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:latlng,
                    clickable:true,
                    map: map,
                    title: '$title',
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    visible: true
                });
                marker1.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
                });
            }
        }
    });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(event) {
            var point = marker.getPosition();// новые координаты маркера: point.lat() и point.lng()
        });

    }

function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

//эта функция используются для определения расстояния между точками на
//поверхности Земли, заданных с помощью географических координат
//результат возвращается в км
distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
    var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
    var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
    var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;

    return d.toFixed(3);
}
  
window.onload = loadScript;
```

```html
<div id="my_map" style="width:100%;height:775px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в событие 'click'

```
if (marker1 != undefined) {
    marker1.setMap(null);
}
```

для массива

```
if (objects_markers != []) {
    for (index in objects_markers) {
        objects_markers[index].setMap(null);
    }
}
```